# Ruby namespacing issues

Tags: ruby, syntax, namespaces

I'm attempting to build a gem for interacting w/ the Yahoo Placemaker API but I'm running into an issue. When I attempt to run the following code I get:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Yahoo::Placemaker::Net
    from /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/yahoo-placemaker-0.0.1/lib/yahoo-placemaker.rb:17:in `extract'
    from (irb):4
    from /Users/Kyle/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

**yahoo-placemaker.rb**

```
require "yahoo-placemaker/version"
require 'json'
require 'ostruct'
require 'net/http'

module Yahoo
  module Placemaker
    def self.extract (text = '')
      host = 'wherein.yahooapis.com'
      payload = {
        'documentContent' => text,
        'appid' => APP_ID,
        'outputType' => 'json',
        'documentType' => 'text/plain'
      }

      req = Net::HTTP::Post.new('/v1/document')
      req.body = to_url_params(payload)
      response = Net::HTTP.new(host).start do |http|
        http.request(req)
      end
      json = JSON.parse(response.body)
      Yahoo::Placemaker::Result.new(json)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have yet to figure out how *exactly* constant name resolution works in Ruby (I think the rules are a bit messy here), but from my experience it could well be that `Net` is looked up in the current namespace instead of the global one. Try using the fully qualified name:

```
::Net::HTTP::Post.new
```

A similar problem could occur in this line:

```
Yahoo::Placemaker::Result
```

You should replace it with either `::Yahoo::Placemaker::Result` or better `Result` (as it lives in the current namespace).

Answer (score 0):

Try requiring net/http before. Ruby is falling back to find it in the module if it isn't defined.

`require 'net/http'`

Comment: Forgot to paste that bit into my post. I've updated my code example.